# Content shrinks in Chrome, Opera but FireFox renders it correctly

Tags: css, google-chrome, opera

OK, First of all after spending much more time I got the solution but I want to know the reason. Whether it is browser bug or I am making some mistake.

Please find following entire code which render this page incorrectly in Google Chrome, Opera and other few browsers. This code work correctly in FireFox. I can't give jsfiddle link as this problem is not getting reproduced in that environment.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
#middlecontainer{width:1000px; height:auto; background-color:#fcf6e2; float:left;}
.matterbox{width:750px; height:auto; float:left;}
.rightsidebox{width:250px; height:auto; float:right;  }
.matter{padding:15px; padding-top:10px;
.heading{ padding:8px; padding-left:5px; font-weight:bold; background-color:#f5d7a7;}
.subheading{font-size:15px; padding-top:5px; color:#663300; font-weight:bold;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="middlecontainer">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x150"  align="top"/>
  <div class="matterbox">
    <div class="matter">
      <div class="heading">Welcome to product registration</div>
      <p class="style1">Important </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightsidebox">
    <div class="matter">
      <p> This is right hand column </p>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you are able to reproduce this code (middlecontainer div becomes invisible) in Chrome or in Opera then you can add `style="float:left"` inline to img tag. This solves this problem but I am trying to find out reason of this problem.

Most importantly FireFox renders this page correctly without any problem.

Please let me know if I need to upload this code on some online web server.

I have uploaded web page on this [Link](https://e0a68005865c6469f758acd43be8b2e71dff5bd1-www.googledrive.com/host/0B4rUu4ji-7j-ejBKMDB6Nkc2eDg)

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the problem that you are facing by looking into this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q2myddq0/

Comment: OK, I have copied web page to google drive, please compare the page in FireFox vs Chrome or Opera. Here is a link [link](https://e0a68005865c6469f758acd43be8b2e71dff5bd1-www.googledrive.com/host/0B4rUu4ji-7j-ejBKMDB6Nkc2eDg)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the browser automatically renders the website to the default zoom unless you state otherwise. You should use a meta tag to declare the zoom for the webpage. 
Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag. If you need more help or this isn't what your looking for please comment back.

Sent from mobile.

Comment: I have checked webpage by adding viewport meta tag but no luck. Basically I am getting this problem not only in tablet / mobile but in Windows XP/7 as well. Please check the this [link](https://e0a68005865c6469f758acd43be8b2e71dff5bd1-www.googledrive.com/host/0B4rUu4ji-7j-ejBKMDB6Nkc2eDg) in FireFox and Chrome or Opera.

Comment: @Silkograph try using clear:both; on the container div which is being hidden

Comment: For time being, I have added `float:left` to all those images to fix this problem of a live website though it is not real solution. I will try your solution and will let you know. Thanks.